# BLE pheripheral not detected when ios app on background

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, ios-bluetooth

i am develop a ble based iOS application on iOS 8.0. i have a peripheral device, that advertise data . am just open my application , the scanning started on viewdidload. then it detect the peripheral and listed in a table view. it is working fine. but  when am switch off the peripheral device, after am start the iOS app, scanning started on didload, and am pressed center key, then app going to background. after am just switch on peripheral device. but it could not detect the device.

(current situation, am switch off and on the bluetooth of an iOS device manually. then background app detected the peripheral and got notification message.)

what is the actual problem with my app? and if any solutions?

Comment: You need to show some code. Perhaps this will help https://github.com/paulw11/BTBackground

Comment: thanks for your comment. i am download project from above link. and tested with my phone and device. but it will work same . peripheral device not detected on background.but it entered into foreground, it working fine.

Comment: What is your peripheral?  How long are you waiting for discovery to occur in the background?  The core Bluetooth programming. Guide says that discovery will take longer in the background.

Comment: it is a board with ble. now am working with your code. after your comment i will check device with your code. but still its not working. am waiting for more than 30 second. nothing happened. any idea?

Comment: any one can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have enabled the proper background mode in the target capabilities page.  Go to the Capabilities tab for your target and switch "Background Modes" to ON, the check "Uses Bluetooth LE accessories".